# Change from self-signed Android app to app signing in Google Play Console

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I have an app on Google Play that needs to be updated. The app is built using Ionic. Until now I have followed these steps:

1. Build APK.
2. Sign APK with a JKS-file using jarsigner.
3. Optimize signed APK using zipalign.
4. Upload optimized APK to Google Play Console.

Recently I made a big update to Ionic and lots of other packages, and also to the development environment itself. When I do a release build now I get an AAB instead of an APK. I need to know how to get this up on Google Play Console.

After doing some reading, I understand that the most convenient way would be to make google handle the signing for me. I would sign my AAB with an upload key and after uploading, Google Play Console will take care of the rest. Is that correct?

Since older versions of the app is already published to Google Play I don't want to mess things up. After I'm done publishing the new version, I want my users to be able to update in the normal way.

So how do I transition from my process with a self-signed APK to using Google Play App signing without messing up the "version history"?

(Sorry if I use the wrong terms for anything here, Android development is not my forte…)

Comment: This is described in https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing